# Including playbook into master playbook

Tags: ansible

How to include child playbook into master playbook? The child playbook contain multiple host groups

Example: child-sample.yml

```
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root

  - tasks:
    name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum: name=httpd state=latest

    name: write the apache config file
    template: src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf

- hosts: databases
  remote_user: root

  - tasks:
    name: ensure postgresql is at the latest version 
    yum: name=postgresql state=latest

    name: ensure that postgresql is started
    service: name=postgresql state=started
```

How should a master-sample.yml be like to include such child playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just as simple as:

master-sample.yaml:

```
- include: child-sample.yml
- include: child-sample2.yml
```

Comment: what if the child-sample1.yml has different host groups for different tasks as shown in the question?

Comment: It doesn't matter. including playbooks is essentially the same as to copy-paste their content into one large file. Ansible then processes it play by play, checking plays' hosts pattern against current inventory and executing tasks on matched servers.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov how can I pass the same variable to both child plays(overwriting the value inside the child play), using the include method?